# Design critique on my apps menu

Tags: interface-design, critique, mobile, user-experience

So, my app has this 'hidden' menu which opens through a button in the toolbar, the idea of the menu is that it's 'behind' the main part of the app.

Also as the data is presented to the user as horizontal cards I thought a good way of representing the user would be as vertical cards.

The menu has a fixed size, so in larger devices, the menu looks a little bit small maybe? That's what is troubling me the most :/

Comment: Hi Levon, thanks for your question. Critique questions are a bit of a weird fit here, because they don't always match with our intended Q&A format. Please have a peek at [our guidelines for critique questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/682) and see whether you can make yours fit those. Thanks! If you have more questions about this site and why we are so anal about some things, have a look at the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help] to get you up to speed about the Stack Exchange model and our site-specific rules.

Answer (score 3):

Your design looks nice an clean which is an excellent start.

However, you don't seem to have a cohesive grid structure and the horizontal menu doesn't work. You don't have a defined center or equal padding on the sides.

I wireframed your app out and laid out the current grid lines.

[image]

As it stands now you have a hamburger menu opening *top -> down* which is unusual because a *top -> down* function is usually handled by a swipe, not a button tap.

Your profile card is nice and large which is good if you want the user to be the focus, but the settings/edit profile/filter ads buttons are way too large and can be simply represented as an icon.

Now to remedy this I suggest you keep the hamburger icon and use it to have your profile page to open *left -> right* and "shove" your main content over.

[image]

Now this looks a lot more organized and is the start of a strong grid structure. Additionally, it leaves you with a lot more space to play around with to add more to your profile tab!

Comment: Thanks! That's a lot of useful information haha. I agree that the buttons are large, but I want to make sure I completely grasp the 'grid structure' aspect; When you say 'You don't have a defined center or equal padding on the sides' I understand that it is because (as your image shows) the lines don't 'land' on top of each other. Problem is, when I use the left -> right menu the same thing will happen, is it better just because it happens less times?